# Replacing the fibre of a fibration.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $p:E\rightarrow X$ be a fibration over a pointed, connected CW complex $X$ with typical fibre $F=p^{-1}(\ast)$. Given another space $F'$ and a homotopy equivalence $F\simeq F'$, is it possible to construct a fibration $p':E'\rightarrow X$ with typical fiber $F'$, together with a fibre homotopy equivalence $E\rightarrow E'$ over $X$?

Comment: What do you mean by '*typical fibre*'?

Comment: In case it helps anyone, my first thought was "look at vector bundles because the fibers are all homotopy equivalent to a point!"  However, there are no counterexamples there: if $s:X\rightarrow E'$ is the zero-section, then $s\circ p$ is the desired fiber homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Here is a question that is related but might be easier to answer: When can you find such a replacement that has every fiber homeomorphic to $F'$?

Comment: Revisiting this question, if $H$ is the monoid of self homotopy equivalences of F homotopic to the identity, doesn’t $BH$ classify fibrations with fiber homotopy equivalent to F? I believe it should do this by picking a topological group model of $\Omega BH$ and some thickened version of $F$ on which the group completion of $H$ acts. Then we have a way of replacing any fibration with a equivalent fibration such that all fibers are homeomorphic.

Comment: @ConnorMalin that's a really nice solution. I think your suggestion works out, although I've never studied the theory in too much detail. If you think you can shape you comment into an answer you should feel free to do so.

Comment: I’ll try later today. I would like to know how to get the group completion of a monoid that acts on a space to act on a suitable replacement today.

Comment: You might be interested in https://www.jstor.org/stable/2046409?seq=1 which accomplishes something (better?) than what I suggest. It replaces your fibration with a fiber bundle.